# Laravel+Vue | Do something and prevent back button if certain condition

Tags: laravel, vue.js, button, mobile, back

As we know, in mobile web-browser, if you click back button, the web-app will go to previous page, right?

But what if I want to make a certain condition which will prevent the web-app to go to previous page.

For example, if a [SweetAlert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2) dialog is popped-up, the back button will close the SweetAlert2 dialog.. but if there is no SweetAlert2 dialog, the back button will go to previous page..

The code I expected is like below:

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
              if(is_swal_open){
                  close_swal_dialog();
                  return false; // NOTE: i expected this should prevent from go to previous page
              }
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is warn the user:

```
if(is_swal_open)
{
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your warning here."; };
}
```

or add an event listener like so:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  if(is_swal_open)
  {
      // Cancel the event
      e.preventDefault();
      // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
      e.returnValue = '';
  }
});
```